# WordPress. Is it possible to programmatically determine if a website is located on a local computer (for example, on Denwer or Open Server)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**General information:** I am developing a plugin for WordPress that needs to send requests. They are sent on real websites, but on a local computer, they need to be sent bypassing CORS.

**In this regard, the question arose:** is it possible to programmatically determine if a website is located on a local computer (for example, on Denwer or Open Server) in order to enable a CORS bypass workaround on local computers and disable it on real websites? And how safe is it?

The CORS bypass mechanism for a local computer, if necessary, is:

```php
// The file "proxy.php" for proxying requests.
<?php
$api_url = 'https://WEBSITE.COM';
$headers = array('X-Auth-Key: CONFIDENTIAL API KEY INFORMATION');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

```js
// The file "script.js" to make a request.
const url = 'proxy.php'
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.text()) // getting a text response
  .then((data) => JSON.parse(data))
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

Comment: You should be able to use JS to check if the current URL starts with `http://localhost`. But that won't allow you to then bypass CORS...CORS restrictions are applied by the server you send the AJAX request to, not by the code which is sending it. The only thing you could do is, in that situation, alter the URL you send the request to, to be the proxy.php script instead of directly to whatever API it's supposed to be calling.